# Is there a program that or way to automatically changes ab|ac|an|db|df to (a(b|c|n)|d(b|f))

Tags: regex, optimization

Rather than testing all the or statements, it will see if the first character matches. The title explains it all.

Comment: What for? Is this just about string manipulation for arbitrary strings, or do you want to write the first form and have a regex engine operate on the second form? If it's the latter, that sounds like you want to optimise regex compilation, which is a large and complex field

Comment: Please spend some time in the [help], particularly in [ask]. When you've done so, you can come back and [edit] your question to make it clear what you're trying to do, include your efforts to solve the problem yourself, explain the difficulty you've encountered, and ask a **specific** question, and we can try to help. A question containing nothing but a title and *the title says it all* for content is not going to work here. If it''s not worth your effort to ask a decent question, it's certainly not worth our effort to answer it.

Comment: @Ixop It’s the first.

Answer (score 1):

When a regex is processed, it first converted to a non-deterministic finite-state automaton (NFA). Then, the NFA is converted to a deterministic finite-state automaton (DFA) which typically results in a larger number of states. The third step is to convert the DFA into a "minimal" DFA with the fewest number of states.
Two regexes are equivalent if and only if they result in identical minimal DFAs. Hence, the two regexes `ab|ac|an|db|df` and `(a(b|c|n)|d(b|f))` which are clearly equivalent result in the same minimal DFA and will perform pattern matching at the same speed. There is no particular reason to prefer one over the other.

Comment: Does this apply to all regex engines?

Comment: @weeeeeee - Your question _Does this apply to all regex engines?_ is not sensible, since anytime anyone can write an abnormal regex engine to which it doesn't apply, but why care for that?